# syntax ERROR or access violation in php bin/console doctrine:query:sql "'cat database.sql'"

Tags: mysql, windows-10, symfony-3.4

I was installing an **existing symfony project** by following these instructions

```
Installation
------------

$ composer install 

Commands
--------

Insert into you crontab. This task will remove featured and published signs from expired listings.

$ php bin/console directory-platform:unpublish-unfeature-listings

Doctrine
--------

$ php bin/console doctrine:database:drop --force

$ php bin/console doctrine:database:create

$ php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force

$ php bin/console doctrine:query:sql "`cat database.sql`"

UserBundle
----------

$ php bin/console fos:user:create testuser test@example.com p@ssword

$ php bin/console fos:user:create sample@example.com --super-admin

Helpers
-------

$ php bin/console assets:install --symlink

$ php bin/console cache:clear --env=dev

$ php bin/console assetic:dump --env prod

Translations
------------

$ php bin/console translation:update en FrontBundle --force --output-format=po --no-prefix # for 3.2
```

but when it comes to running this command line

```
$ php bin/console doctrine:query:sql "`cat database.sql`"
```

this error appears(I tried replacing **cat** with **type** because I m working on **windows 10** but the same error kept showing

[image: ERROR]

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this command line in my own terminal (I use gitbash on windows) and it worked. It is supposed to print all the sql command then to run it.

To do it on a windows terminal you have to do this :
`php bin/console doctrine:query:sql $(cat database.sql)`

Hope it works.

Comment: yes but I really need to run it because in the index it says that this command is going to import database.sql into my database, do you know how to do it on windows?

Comment: Try that : `php bin/console doctrine:query:sql $(cat database.sql)`

Comment: thank you but I did it manually by copying and runnig all database script in my database SQL (phpmyadmin)